# Palabras con significados opuestos

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Hoy me llamó la atención una declaración del Jefe de Gobierno de la Ciudad de Buenos Aires, que fue transcripta de este modo:

"Larreta criticó al Gobierno [Nacional] y dijo que [el Gobierno Nacional] tiene “desprecio” por la inseguridad"

¿Desprecio por la inseguridad o desprecio por la seguridad?

En DLE, encontramos dos definiciones que, al menos en el caso en cuestión, resultan contradictorias:

1. tr. Desestimar y tener en poco.
2. tr. Desairar o desdeñar.

Lo que Larreta quiso decir es que el Gobierno Nacional desestima, o resta importancia, a la inseguridad (y yo digo que, al hacerlo, desdeña la seguridad).

La pregunta es, ¿se les ocurren otras palabras que, por su uso en el contexto, tengan significados opuestos?

NOTA: En respuesta a los comentarios de acuerdo con los cuales no habría contradicción, doy otro ejemplo:

Una persona que desprecia (= no aprecia, no valora) la vida desprecia (= desestima, ignora) el peligro. Si bien es verdad que en ambos casos no se da importancia (a la vida y al peligro), en el primer caso hay una falta de valoración positiva (hacia la vida) mientras que en el segundo hay una falta de valoración negativa (hacia el peligro). Creo que allí radica la contradicción entre los dos significados que hizo que, cuando escuché la noticia, me resultara confusa: ¿desprecio por la seguridad como un bien positivo o desprecio por la inseguridad como un hecho negativo?

Comment: No sé cómo decirlo, o si estoy forzando la lógica, pero no me parece que aquí haya "significados opuestos". Pienso que si alguien no le da importancia a la seguridad, tampoco le está dando importancia a la inseguridad.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quires decir con "resultan contradictorias" en la frase.

Comment: Agregué una nota aclaratoria. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Si, interesante, porque la doble negación, parece aquí un yerro, que desde el punto de vista lógico contradice el sentido  que se le quiso dar (al estar técnicamente expresando que [el Gob Nacional] tiene "**poco aprecio**" [desprecio) **por la inseguridad**, lo cual no sería criticable)

A tu pregunta de otras palabras de significados contradictorios, hay una expresión que hace mucho tiempo —en la secundaria, con un compañero— no lográbamos interpretar por afirmativa o positiva. El diario deportivo decía que "se descartaba que estuviera" tal jugador para el partido del clasíco.

Esa construcción **descartar que si** me produce una disonancia-logica. Googleando se encuentran frases de ese tenor (interpretables pero contructivamente ambiguas):

> "Marchesín no fue citado esta vez, aunque se descarta que si estará para la gira por Nigeria y Polonia. Felicitaciones Diego

Objetable siendo que [descartar](https://dle.rae.es/descartar?m=form) es

> "excluir, eliminar algo o alquien"

Hay muchas de estas instancias, otra que naturalizamos y entendemos, podría ser

> **"antes que nada"**

para significar "primeramente" (lo cual sería antes que *todo* o *toda otra cosa*, pero se dice `nada`, e igualmente, por costumbre, comprendemos su sentido.

De naturaleza parecida [al uso](https://twitter.com/JessMarnCharles/status/297932774080409600) de

> **"mas que nada"**

que significa `sobre todo` o `principalmente`

Comment: Me gusta especialmente "descartar". Es verdad que puede ser "sobrentender (como incluido)" o "excluir".}

Answer (score 3):

Más que por frases y oraciones, he querido optar por palabras que muchas veces utilizamos y que pueden llevar en ocasiones a confusiones o malentendidos por su ambivalencia.

- **Alquilar** -La confusión puede presentarse cuando decimos u oímos que *fulan*o ha alquilado algo y no sabemos si ese alguien lo ha alquilado como arrendador o como arrendatario.
- **Me enerva** -Comúnmente utilizamos la palabra para referirnos a un estado de nerviosismo. Sin embargo en menor medida, se utiliza también con el sentido de debilitar o quitar las fuerzas.
- **En Absoluto** -Puede emplearse para decir "de manera general y terminante" o también justo lo contrario, es decir, no.
- **Eres un animal** -A veces lo oímos decir a alguien y no sabemos si el que lo dice lo hace como un insulto o como un halago.
- **Eres un monstruo** -El mismo caso que el anterior.
- **Doy clase** -"Doy clase", "Da clase", "Dió clase"... a veces en determinadas conversaciones tenemos la sensación de no saber muy bien si quien habla es el que imparte la clase o es quien recibe la clase.
- **Frases con la palabra Sancionar** -Según las conversaciones y los contextos, sancionar sirve tanto para autorizar o aprobar algo como para prohibir o castigar a alguien y a veces en determinados momentos puede llevar a alguien a confusión.
- **Distender** -puede significar tanto disminuir una tensión como causarla.

Comment: Me gustó especialmente "sancionar" (dictar una norma o penalizar su incumplimiento).